# strongSwan routing issue with roadwarrior behind NAT

Tags: linux, routing, nat, ipsec

Using the following ipsec.conf configuration:

```
conn %default
        ikelifetime=60m
        keylife=20m
        keyingtries=3
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyexchange=ikev2
        esp=aes-aes256-sha-modp1024,aes256-sha512-modp4096
        ike=aes-aes256-sha-modp1024,aes256-sha512-modp4096
        leftcert=servercert.pem    
        leftid=server.strongswan.org
        lefthostaccess=yes
        leftfirewall=yes

conn roadwarrior
        left=%any
        right=%any
        leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
        rightsourceip=%dhcp
        auto=add
```

When a client connects from behind the NAT (e.g. private IP range, for example 192.168.1.0/24) it's local routing (in the 192.xxx range) doesn't work anymore as it is forwarded via the tunnel (gateway has no idea about external private networks).

The question is - how to let all traffic go through the tunnel *except* for the client's own network.

Comment: That depends on the client. Refer to the [notes about split-tunneling](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling#Split-Tunneling) on the strongSwan wiki.

Comment: This question already answered here http://serverfault.com/questions/709979/allow-strongswan-roadwarrior-to-access-local-lan